# What does exclamation mark mean in FT8 CQ calls in WSJT?

Tags: software, ft8

For example, in this screenshot:

[image]

WSJT shows !Italy, !Serbia, !U.S.A. What does it mean?

Comment: Have run into some interesting suffixes to CQ callin in FT8, that do not ring a bell.
Seen callers sending 'CQ NA callsign' and several different ones; Very familiar with CQ DX, but in 20 years of ham, have not seen/heard some of these suffixes....anyone know heir real meaning? Thanks

Comment: @KV7D Please ask this as a separate question. I am sure you will get some useful answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is something that is activated by "Show DXCC entity and worked before status" (selectable on the "Settings" > "General tab"). From the manual:

> When this option is checked WSJT-X appends some additional information
>   to all CQ messages displayed in the Band Activity window. The name of
>   the DXCC entity is shown, abbreviated if necessary. Your “worked
>   before” status for this callsign (according to log file wsjtx_log.adi)
>   is flagged with a single character and a change of background color,
>   as follows:
>
> !  Default color bright purple: New DXCC entity
>
> ~  Light pink: You have already worked this DXCC entity but not this
>   station
>
> Green: You have previously worked the calling station

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the FT8 client you are using is parsing the callsign of people calling CQ, and displaying their DXCC entity prefixed by a !.